# Keep list indentation in doxygen between successive comment blocks

Tags: list, doxygen, indentation

I would like to use Doxygen comments in my code to create bulleted lists that complement the function description in the generated documentation.
For example, the following snippet code:

```
/**
 * Function x
 */
void function (void) {
/// List:
/// - comment A
;
;
/// + comment B
;
;
/// * comment C

}
```

should produce such a list:

```
List:
- A
  - B
    - C
```

Unfortunately, Doxygen seems not to keep the indentation level from one comment block to another of the same function. Is there a workaround to that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After researching for the past few hours, I've come to the conclusion that indented lists across non-contiguous doxygen comments is not possible.

I was able to get indented lists to work in block comments easily:

```
/**
-# Item 1
    -# Subitem 1
    -# Subitem 2
-# Item 2
*/
```

Switched to single line comments and it still worked:

```
/// -# Item 1
///     -# Subitem 1
///     -# Subitem 2
/// -# Item 2
```

When I added code in between single line comments, doxygen stopped indenting subitems.

Comment: Similarly, it doesn't even increment numeric lists when there is an interruption.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17621121/documenting-unit-tests-in-line-with-code

Answer (score 2):

It is actually possible to do it using the HTML format

```
//! <ul><li> Entering a condition:<ul>
if (xx)
{
    //! <li> something
    C=A+B;

    //! <li> something else
    D="lol";
}
//! </ul></ul>
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me, I receive warnings during generation and my list is not parsed completely.