# Documenting Unit Tests in line with code

Tags: unit-testing, doxygen

I'm trying to use doxygen to document my unit tests, but I'd like to document them in-line with the code instead of in the test header to reduce copy/paste errors when making similar tests.  Of note, I'm using the RTF output format.

```
    /** @brief A method for testing doxygen method documentation
     * @test
     *     -#Step 1
     *     -#Step 2
     *     -#Step 3
     */
    [TestMethod()]
    public void DoxygenScratchPadInHeader()
    {
        // code that may or may not be in sync with header
    }

    /** @brief A method for testing doxygen method documentation
     * @test
     */
    [TestMethod()]
    public void DoxygenScratchPadInLine()
    {
        /// @par
        ///     -#  Initialize the value to 0
        int i = 0;

        /// @par
        ///     -# Add a number
        i += 3;

        /// @par
        ///     -# Assert that the number is three
        Assert.AreEqual(3, i);
    }
```

Test List Output:

Member UpdateProtocolQATests.CUpdateProtocolTest.DoxygenScratchPadInHeader  ()

1. Step 1
2. Step 2
3. Step 3

Member UpdateProtocolQATests.CUpdateProtocolTest.DoxygenScratchPadInLine  ()

{note no steps here}

Function description output:

void UpdateProtocolQATests.CUpdateProtocolTest.DoxygenScratchPadInHeader ()

A method for testing doxygen method documentation. 
Test:

1. Step 1
2. Step 2
3. Step 3

void UpdateProtocolQATests.CUpdateProtocolTest.DoxygenScratchPadInLine ()

A method for testing doxygen method documentation. 
Test:

```
1.  Initialize the value to 0


1.  Add a number


1.  Assert that the number is three
```

{displaying last bit as code because stackoverflow is correcting the repeated 1. to 1. 2. 3... which is what I actually want in the end...}

Any better ideas for implementing in-line test step documentation?  I don't care so much about the steps not appearing in the test list, we can live with just the references to the functions.

Comment: Sometimes there are regulatory requirements to fulfill.  The FDA does not specialize in understanding clear code, they sometimes want everything laid out in paragraph form.  My test is less than ten lines of code and could easily be understood by developers, but not necessarily by non-developers.

Comment: This pattern of having more lines of comment than code is fairly standard in the medical device companies I've worked with.

Comment: You have a very good point; I think we've all read at some point or another about the Therac-25. Sorry for the unconstructive comment.

Comment: Yeah, I've never built a component quite that critical, but we have to carefully document the fact that the component is not that critical, and document and test the code enough to give the FDA confidence in our work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm quite sympathetic to your plight, but as far as I can tell, Doxygen really is *only* designed to document specific code-objects (files, classes, namespaces, variables, etc) rather than arbitrary lines of code.

At the moment, the only possibility I can think of for circumventing this shortcoming is to generate comments that include the actual code that you're wanting to document via the [`\code` command](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdcode).

There are two ways I can think of for accomplishing this:

1. Put some sort of special string (say, for instance, `DOXY_INLINE_CODE`) in the Doxy comments that should be associated with a single line of code. Then write a filter (see [FILTER_PATTERNS](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_filter_patterns)) to replace this string with `\code <nextline> \endcode` where `<nextline>` is the next line of code that the filter sees. I'm not sure where Doxygen would put these comments or how they'd look; they might be pretty ugly, unfortunately. (One odd behavior I dislike is that the `\code` command seems to strip leading spaces, so you wouldn't get indentation to work correctly.)
2. Write a "Doxygen runner" that would automatically generate `.dox` files from your code before calling `doxygen`. These auto-generated `.dox` files would contain documentation generated from corresponding `.cpp` or other source files. You can use various Doxygen commands to [link back to](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/docblocks.html#structuralcommands) the documentation of the actual source code, and you can also [insert a copy](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdcopydoc) of the `.dox` documentation in the source code documentation (or vice-versa).

These are hacks, and you'd have to fiddle around with Doxygen quite a bit to get it to handle this case nicely, but I hope these suggestions help somewhat. Best of luck. (I'm currently working on doing something similar to get Doxygen to nicely document Google Tests, also in the context of a project for a highly-regulated industry.)

Answer (score 0):

I remembered coming across this question when I was looking for a similar solution. I wanted to document user testing procedures as close as possible to their corresponding unit tests or groups of unit tests. The following is a subset of the solution we implemented with Doxygen groups/sub-groups.

A separate `manual-test.dox` file is defined to create a top-level group and several sub-groups under which specific manual tests are collected.

```
/**
@defgroup manualtest Manual Testing Instructions
@{
This section contains a collection of manual testing...

@defgroup menutest Menu Tests

@defgroup exporttest Import/Export Tests

@}
*/
```

The following shows a sample of a Java unit test class with unit test documentation and manual testing instructions.

```
public MenuTests {
   ...

   /**
    * @addtogroup menutest
    * **Open File Test**
    * 
    * The purpose of this test is to...
    *
    * -# Do something
    * -# Verify something
    */
   /**
    * This unit test verifies that the given file can be created via
    * the File->Open... menu handler. It...
    */
   @Test
   public void open_file_test() {
      ...
   }
}
```

The resulting HTML documentation will include a **Manual Testing Instruction** page
under the **Modules** section. Said page will contain markup details as given in `manual-test.dox` and links to module pages for each of the defined sub-groups, such as **Menu Tests**.

The **Menu Tests** page will show all manual unit testing steps added to this
sub-group, thereby providing a separate document that can be included
by reference as part of a Software Test Plan or User Test Plan.

The only caveat is that there are no means to explicitly define the order in which test instructions are added to groups. When defined in a single class, they are added in the order they are defined and multiple classes are parsed in alphabetic order.

For projects that required more control over how tests are collected, Doxygen is used to create XML output. Test cases are extracted using an XSLT template and ordered as needed, but that is another question off its own.

Answer (score -1):

Use a tool which supports document generation from inline comments:

- [NaturalDocs](http://www.naturaldocs.org/documenting/walkthrough.html#ExtraDocumentation)
- [ASCIIDoctorJ](https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctorj)

Doxygen has [helpers for perl](http://www.doxygen.nl/helpers.html), which is what NaturalDocs is written in.

Comment: Client requires Doxygen.  Another tool is not an option.